# How to implement azure service bus in react-native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, message-queue, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

Need to setup queue subscriber in client react-native app. Tried using the @azure/service-bus npm package, which uses the crypto module inside. While react-native does not support inbuilt nodejs modules, i got to know of some hacks to use those. But despite trying multiple approaches, i am unable to make it work.

Is there a good way to implement service-bus on react-native client side?

What else can i do to subscribe to the queue beside setting up my own server and use a socket connection to pass messages to client?

Comment: The SDK is expected to work in browser environments, so I believe it should work for React Native as well if you [bundle](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/documentation/Bundling.md) it. But note that this connection will not work when the app is in the background. Could you share more details on the exact error that you are seeing?